# Snowflake: create or replace table vs insert overwrite into table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a table in Snowflake that will be used by a SQL Server stored procedure (using `Openquery`) to return data.

When the Snowflake task executes to refresh the data in the table, is it better to run a `"create or replace table"` statement or use an `"insert overwrite into table"` statement?

I'm looking to avoid a period of time when there is no data available to the SQL Server stored procedure.

Is one of these approaches better for keeping existing data available until the task to refresh the table finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatfield,

There are a handful of ways to tackle this and the 2 that you mentioned are the easiest and probably the most used. Since Snowflake works based on the AutoCommit premise you should be able to use "Create or Replace" and if there are queries coming in that is consuming the data while the "Create or Replace" is still running, the results will still return the old results until the the "Create or Replace" has been fully committed. This is part of read committed isolation level which is what Snowflake uses for tables currently. If you wanted to ensure this your Create or Replace is running as a transaction the you could throw the BEGIN at the beginning and COMMIT at the end but it shouldn't be required if you are only executing that single "Create or Replace" statement.

There is another approach that may be of interest and comes in handy from time to time. The data flow would look like this, create a new table with the new data you want to use. Then in the following step you would rename the current table to something else and then rename the new table with what used to be the current table name. You can wrap that in a transaction to ensure the rollback just in case it fails. The 2 ALTER TABLE statements to do the renaming would happen in a blink of an eye. There are different reason to use or not to use this method. Somethings you will need to take into account if you go with this approach and that is if you had any permissions on the original/current table, you will need to apply those to the new table and if you had clustered keys on the original table you will also need to apply those to the new table.

I hope this helps in some way.